# Sample Buffer Delegate Swift 2 For Real Time Video Filter

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to create a light intensity reader using the camera on an iPhone in swift. The idea being it takes the intensity component for all the pixels and averages them to give me a single value. I don't need a preview of the camera. I have been piecing together a couple tutorials to try and get it to work, and so far have come up with the code below.
camDeviceSetup() runs on ViewDidLoad, cameraSetup() runs on a button press.

I run into an error on the line that starts "videoDeviceOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate", it says it can not convert value of type FirstViewController (the view controller) to expected argument.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
// If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var videoDeviceOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
// AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is a subclass of CALayer that you use to display video as it is being captured by an input device.
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

func camDeviceSetup() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }
    }
    if captureDevice != nil {
        let err : NSError? = nil
        captureSession.addInput(try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))

        if err != nil {
            print("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
}

func cameraSetup() {
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    videoDeviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoDeviceOutput!.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
    videoDeviceOutput!.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

//This is the line that gets stuck and not sure why
    videoDeviceOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("VideoBuffer", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL))

    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDeviceOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoDeviceOutput)
    }

    captureSession.startRunning() 
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // Think once the delegate is correctly set my algorithm for finding light intensity goes here

}
```

Comment: The issues on that line was down to me not declaring AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in the class at the top of my ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues on that line was down to me not declaring AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in the class at the top of my ViewController.

Comment: did u assign the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate to the vc?